# Using JavaScript to encode morsecode

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert any text string into Morse Code in the simplest way possible. I am very new to programming so please can you give me some advice on what methods i could use.

I have so far just written a phrase(string) and an Array holding the Morse Code but i am struggling on what steps to use next on how to take each character of the string then checking it with the array and printing out the Morse Code equivalent of the string.

```
var phrase = "go down like a lead balloon";

var morseCode = [".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-",     ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."]

for(i=0; i<phrase.length; i++){

c = phrase.charAt(i);

WScript.echo(c + " | " + i);
}
```

Comment: That would be encoding, not decoding.

Comment: `phrase.charCodeAt(n)` will give you the numeric (unicode) code for the n+1th character, 65 for A, 66 for B and so on, use that (-65) as a key for your morse map; alternatively use a lookup  `morse = {A: ".-", B: "-..." ...` read via `morse["A"]`

Comment: My goodness, are you using the windows script host? Abandon ship! Seriously. Use something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or Scratchpad on Firefox (from the developer tools). The windows script host does __not__ behave like the javascript engines of browsers. It does strange and unusual things with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you have to strip off all the characters you can't encode:

```
phrase = phrase.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, "");
```

Using [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), you'll end up with a string of only alphabetic characters. We also convert all the letter to lowercase for semplicity.

Then, inside the for loop:

```
c = phrase.charCodeAt(i);
```

That would convert the letter into its equivalent ASCII code value. The corrisponding morse code would then be `morseCode[c - 97]`.

As Gerald Schneider suggested, you can improve this encoding with numbers too, but the code would be a bit more complex.

Comment: morse code does have digits and some special characters.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Yes, indeed, but they're not present in `morseCode`. I suppose they are all letters.

Comment: Just an addendum for completeness: you can also use an object with all the lowercase alphanumeric characters as keys and their morse code equivalents as values. This would mean converting the string to all lowercase and skipping characters not in the object/dictionary.

Comment: @ivy_lynx Yes, indeed. But I think the best would be having a complete conversion table.

Comment: Thank you all so much this is helping me a lot, been stuck on this for a little while.

Answer (score 12):

You could use an dictionary, like this:

```
var alphabet = {
    'a': '.-',    'b': '-...',  'c': '-.-.', 'd': '-..',
    'e': '.',     'f': '..-.',  'g': '--.',  'h': '....',
    'i': '..',    'j': '.---',  'k': '-.-',  'l': '.-..',
    'm': '--',    'n': '-.',    'o': '---',  'p': '.--.',
    'q': '--.-',  'r': '.-.',   's': '...',  't': '-',
    'u': '..-',   'v': '...-',  'w': '.--',  'x': '-..-',
    'y': '-.--',  'z': '--..',  ' ': '/',
    '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--', '4': '....-', 
    '5': '.....', '6': '-....', '7': '--...', '8': '---..', 
    '9': '----.', '0': '-----', 
}

"This is a sentence containing numbers: 1 2 3 4 5"
    .split('')            // Transform the string into an array: ['T', 'h', 'i', 's'...
    .map(function(e){     // Replace each character with a morse "letter"
        return alphabet[e.toLowerCase()] || ''; // Lowercase only, ignore unknown characters.
    })
    .join(' ')            // Convert the array back to a string.
    .replace(/ +/g, ' '); // Replace double spaces that may occur when unknow characters were in the source string.

// "- .... .. ... / .. ... / .- / ... . -. - . -. -.-. . / -.-. --- -. - .- .. -. .. -. --. / -. ..- -- -... . .-. ... / .---- / ..--- / ...-- / ....- / ....."
```

Comment: A "scentence" is a phrase that smells? XD

Comment: Oh man good job, this is way more elegant than what I was just writing :P I completely forgot `.map()` - nice one, +1.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned you could convert the array to an object for a one to one mapping. This way you don't have to worry about errant characters getting into the output because the decode function will filter them out if they're not present as a key.

```
var morseObj = {};
for (var i = 97, l = 97 + morseCode.length; i < l; i++) {
  morseObj[String.fromCharCode(i)] = morseCode[i - 97];
}
```

And then have an decode function:

```
function encode(sentence) {
  var output = '';
  for (var i = 0, l = sentence.length; i < l; i++) {
    var letter = sentence[i].toLowerCase();
    if (morseObj[letter]) { output += morseObj[letter] + ' '; }
  }
  return output;
}

encode('My name is Andy'); // "-- -.-- -. .- -- . .. ... .- -. -.. -.-- "
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4p74k3ho/1)

Comment: You might want to replace `decode` with `encode`. (Just nitpicking, really)

Comment: Oh, and you're going to have to add spaces between morse characters. As well as some kind of separator between words. I mean: Does `"-.---..---......-.-..-.--"` start with a `T` or a `N` or a `Y`?

Comment: I can understand the space between characters, words not so much. I've edited the code so that it's lowercase because as you rightly pointed out, the output didn't make sense.

Comment: In written morse, something like a pipe or a slash is often used to separate words. It makes it easier to read to those that know morse. (And easier to decode, since otherwise, you'd get `"mynameisandy"` as a result)

Comment: Cheers Cerbrus. I did have a quick scan of the morse code wiki but couldn't find out about word separation.

Comment: Hm, I don't think it's an official guideline. It's just something I've seen here and there.